# How can I include a general html text with php?

Tags: php, html

I want a simple method to include some html text with php functions. Like creating a simple array with functions like: Ex. "about_us_text => About us text example etc.." . Which will be the easiest way to do this ? And how will I include the two files to work as one? Thanks.

```
$lang = array_merge($lang, array(
    'ADD_ATTACHMENT'            => 'Upload attachment',
    'ADD_ATTACHMENT_EXPLAIN'    => 'If you wish to attach one or more files enter the details below.',
    'ADD_FILE'                  => 'Add the file',
    'ADD_POLL'                  => 'Poll creation',
```

Comment: where exactly do you want to include html ? some thing like '<p>About us</p>' ? and what what do you mean by two files?

Comment: Please explain properly.

Comment: yes. <p>{ABOUT_US}</p> and I want to define text intro a php file like 'ABOUT_US' => "Lorem ipsum ......................"

Answer (score 0):

This code will automatically replace `{ADD_ATTACHMENT}` with `Upload attachment`

```
<?php
include 'lang.php';
ob_start();
include ('page_to_display.php');
$html=ob_get_clean();
for ($lang as $k=>$v)
    $html=str_replace('{'.$k.'}',$v,$html);
echo $html();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lengthy html text it is better to put it in its own file and define that file as a translations/constants file. Include that php file in your function/array. keeps it clean
http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php

Your constants file `lang_constants_en.php` might by like

```
<?php
define('ABOUT_US', '<p>About Us</p>');`
```

in your function called `dump_html()`

```
<?php
include('lang_constants_en.php');

function dump_html(){
    echo "Other header html" . ABOUT_US;
}
dump_html();
```

Comment: And how can I call the defined constant in the html file to appear on the web? I mean ,after I define it in the .php file , I want to access the defined function in the html.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to use like phpbb3 !

```
if (!defined('IN_PHPBB'))
{
    exit;
}
    if (empty($lang) || !is_array($lang))
    {
        $lang = array();
    } 
    $lang = array_merge($lang, array(
        'ACTION'                => 'Action',
        'ACTION_NOTE'           => 'Action/Note',
```

And they use {ACTION} for text. That is what I want... not html dump and other things....